# How to enable & disable this option?

Tags: unity

[image]
How to enable and disable this option only, not the whole object with C# ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly you're trying to achieve is to disable just a component and not the whole gameobject.

You can get any component (on the current object) using

```
var component = GetComponent<Type>();
```

Where `Type` is the component you want to get. Examples in your case:

```
var camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
var canvas = GetComponent<Canvas>();
```

Here `GetComponent` is called on the current gameObject where your script is, but you can call it on another gameObject, it's a public function.

Then all components can be enabled/disabled:

```
component.enabled = false; // Disable
component.enabled = true; // Enable

// Examples
camera.enabled = true; 
canvas.enabled = false;
```

Finally, notice that the checkbox only appears in the inspector next to a component if some methods are found by Unity (usually: `Start` and `Update`).

Comment: API reference: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour-enabled.html